# How to make CMake execute some script after it generates visual studio solution

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am using CMake to build a project. I want to execute some script(say python script) after CMake is done generating the solution so that I won't have to execute it manually everytime.
I am using Cmake 2.8. Does anybody know any userhook or something which Cmake provides for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute a command *during CMake's build* then use [execute_process](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aexecute_process).

Comment: but that is post configure right? I want the script to be executed post generate.

Comment: @tejas yes my mistake, that intent is clear from the question. Edited the answer.

Comment: Yes but that is during the execution of CMake. I want to execute script after CMake is done.